# Django - Modelform is_valid()=True but form.errors returns [{}, {}, {}, {}]

Tags: django, django-forms

The formset pass the `is_valid()` verification but `{{ formset.errors }}` returns `[{}, {}, {}, {}]` in template. (One {} for each form in the modelformset_factory formset.

I dont understand that the form is saved successfully anyway...

```
def setMapOptions(request, map_name):
    map_selected = EzMap.objects.get(map_name=map_name, created_by=request.user)
    layers_ordered = LayerMapOptions.objects.filter(ezmap=map_selected).order_by('position')
    layerForm = modelformset_factory(LayerMapOptions, form=LayerMapOptionsForm, extra=0)

    if request.POST:
        pk_list = [int(x) for x in request.POST.get("layersOrder").split(',')]
        formset = layerForm(request.POST, queryset=layers_ordered)
        if formset.is_valid():
            for form in formset:
                instance = form.instance
                instance.position = pk_list.index(instance.pk)
                instance.save()

    else:
        formset = ezMapOptionFormSet(user=request.user, instance=map_selected)
        formset2 = layerForm(queryset=layers_ordered)

    tmsURL = "http://" + request.get_host() + "/ezmapping/tms/"
    return render_to_response("ezmapping/manage_map_Options.html", {'formset': formset, 'map': map_selected, 'layersOrder': layers_ordered, 'tmsURL' : tmsURL, }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

form:

```
class ModelLinkWidget(forms.Widget):
    def __init__(self, obj, attrs=None):
        self.object = obj
        super(ModelLinkWidget, self).__init__(attrs)

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        if self.object.pk:
            return mark_safe(
                u'<a href="/ezmapping/layer/edit/%s">%s</a>' %\
                      (
                       self.object.pk, self.object
                       )
            )
        else:
            return mark_safe(u'')

class LayerMapOptionsForm(ModelForm):
    link = forms.CharField(label='link', required=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LayerMapOptionsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['link'].widget = ModelLinkWidget(self.instance.layer)

    class Meta:
        model = LayerMapOptions
        fields =  ['link', 'visible']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`formset.errors` is a list whose entries correspond to its forms. When the formset is valid, there are no errors on the individual forms, therefore `formset.errors` is a list of empty dictionaries.

This means that `formset.errors` will evaluate to `True` even when the formset is valid, because a non empty list always evaluates to `True`. Another gotcha is that `len(formset.errors)` returns the number of forms in the formset, not the number of errors. In Django 1.6 there is a new `formset.total_error_count()` method to solve this problem.

Note that there is also a `formset.non_form_errors()` method, which returns the errors not related to any particular form.

See the docs on [formset validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/formsets/#formset-validation) for more information.